# Why div element is not expanding back to the original size when change the browser window?

Tags: html, css, angular, angularjs

### This is HTML

```html
<div class="analysis-area"><div class="chart-wrapper"><div class="chart-panel"><p-chart #pAccuracyChart type="bar" [data]="accuracyChartData" width="500px" height="100%" [responsive]="true" [options]="accuracyChartOptions"></p-chart></div>
```

```html
    <div class="accuracyChart">
        <p-chart #pAccuracyChart type="bar" [data]="accuracyChartData" width="500px" height="100%" [responsive]="true" [options]="accuracyChartOptions"></p-chart>
     </div>
  </div>
<div class="table-wrapper">
   <div class="data-table"></div>
   <div class="staticalTbl">/div>                  
</div>
```

### This is CSS

```css
.analysis-area{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction:column;

.chart-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

.chart-panel{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
 }        

.accuracyChart{
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
         }
     }

     .table-wrapper{
        width: 100%;
        height: 40%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
            .data-table{
               height: 100%;
               width: 50%;
            }
       .staticalTbl{
          height: 100%;
          width: 50%;
        }
     }
  }
```

Parent div contains an analysis area inside with `chart-wrapper` and `table-wrapper` elements. The `chart-wrapper` contains two PrimeNG charts.

When the browser window size changes, the `chart-wrapper` should expand, and the `table-wrapper` should occupy the remaining space.

The problem arises when using `p-chart`. When I zoom out, the charts become larger because the `chart-wrapper` is expanding, but the `p-chart`'s height does not change.

However, if I use empty `div` elements with the properties `width: 100%` and `height: 100%`, there are no issues.

Comment: What version of Angular are you using?

Answer (score 0):

missing close the div tag in:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <style>
  
  .analysis-area{
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction:column;

.chart-wrapper{
    width: 100%;
    flex: 1;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

.chart-panel{
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
 }        

.accuracyChart{
            width: 50%;
            height: 100%;
         }
     }

     .table-wrapper{
        width: 100%;
        height: 40%;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
            .data-table{
               height: 100%;
               width: 50%;
            }
       .staticalTbl{
          height: 100%;
          width: 50%;
        }
     }
  }
*{
  border:1px solid gray;
}
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h1>My First Heading</h1>
  <p>My first paragraph.</p>


  <div class="accuracyChart">
    <p-chart #pAccuracyChart type="bar" [data]="accuracyChartData" width="500px" height="100%" [responsive]="true" [options]="accuracyChartOptions"></p-chart>
 
  </div>
  <div class="table-wrapper">
    <div class="data-table"></div>
    <div class="staticalTbl"></div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```